# A Customized Title

Tags: titles

Good morning.
Unfortunately I'm stuck in this situation: I need to create a command that repeats what you see in the picture.

If it were possible, it would also serve that the number (1.1, 1.2, 1.3...) be progressive, without having to type it.

Thanks for any answers and sorry for the English, but I work with an automatic translator.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% new commands
\newcommand\tit{\Large\hspace{30mm}\vspace{20mm}}

\begin{document}

\tit
1.1 Lorem Ipsum

\tit
1.2 Lorem Ipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are these (sub)section headings or the start of a  numbered list?

Comment: Headings. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=1.\arabic*]
  \item Lorem Ipsum
  \item Lorem Ipsum
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! ... And without use enumerate? Is it a possibility?